# is there any way to detect a deleted consumer group in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

having a Kafka server using Kafka to store consumer groups offsets, I wonder if `__consumer-offsets` topic would have an event for a deleted consumer group?
or how can I subscribe to this event without asking Kafka if a specific consumer group exists

Answer (score 0):

There is no such Kafka event when a topic with `cleanup.policy=delete` removes a segment of messages.

You could parse the broker server logs and look for the LogCleaner actions and push them into a Kafka topic if you really wanted to, but you still would not know what groups were being removed.